# Android Studio Library module reference

Tags: android, unit-testing, reference, module, gradle

I'm trying to setup my project so i can run unit tests and automation tests thru Android Studio. After many attempts i ended up with this structure on my project.

Project
   -> Android Module (With the real app where i run the automation tests)
   -> Java Library Module (With business logic classes and all things that i need to run unit tests)

I'm also referencing some Jar Lib on the Java Module in order to use some common code that i've wrote.

The Android Module references the Library Module as can be seen on the following sample gradle script:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':Core')
    compile files(':Core/libs/fake_lib.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
}
```

The second line on the dependencies section was need for the project can get assembled and run, but the problem is that on the first call to any class that have some reference to the library, the app crashes with a **NoClassDefFoundError**

Does anyone knows why and how to fix?

Comment: Replace ':Core/libs/fake_lib.jar' to '../Core/libs/fake_lib.jar'. Or better to include this library to core itself

Comment: @EugenMartynov you are right, this change made it work, although, to my understanding, i shouldn't have to reference this lib on the Android Project since it would come along with the Java Library. So i ended up putting the library on my local maven and it resolved this two issues. Anyway thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this JAR is a common library that i will use to many projects, i ended up placing it on my local maven repository and referenced it like other maven artifacts.

This way i don't have to reference it on both projects (Android and Java Library) just in the library, which i think is better approach.

Comment: Be careful with maven local repository. This is common issue with non-reproducible builds on other developer/CI machines

Comment: It's good advice, sure it would be a problem on a development team but, in my case, i'm just developing some private works.